# Connection error via express app

Tags: node.js, express, mysqli, handlebars.js, electron

I am using express app being run through electron. What`s happening is that a list of avaialble items is displayed to the user, and upon click it runs a python code using the information of that item.

Below is the routes

```
 let sqlSelectBoxInformation = "SELECT DISTINCT longestDimension, box_id from box WHERE occupied ='unoccupied'";

         connectionBoxInformation.query(sqlSelectBoxInformation, function(err, rows, fields) {

        if (!err) {
          // Check to see if the user entered hashtag is found in the database
          // Create a variable to track if the item was found

           if(rows.length > 0){


          var wasFound = false;
          //  if (databaseHashtag == userEnteredHashtag) {
            console.log(databaseHashtag);

                var data = {
                 rows: rows,
                 userHashtag: databaseHashtag
                }
                res.render('delivery/chooseBox', data);

               // Change the variable to true
               wasFound = true;
          }
      else {
          res.render('delivery/alloccupied');
      }
```

Below is the view

```
 <h3>Please begin by selecting the box size below:</h3>

<!-- add if statement-->

        <form method="post" action="/delivery/chooseBoxSelected">
                           <input type="hidden" name="userHashtag" value="{{userHashtag}}">

            {{#each rows}}


            <input type="hidden" name="boxSelectedValue" value="{{this.box_id}}">
           <input type="hidden" name="boxSelectedDimension" value="{{this.longestDimension}}">

            <button class="btn-dimension" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                &nbsp;Longest dimension {{this.longestDimension}}"
            </button>

                {{/each}}
```

What happens is that when only one item is pulled from the database and displayed as a list to the user, upon click it works. When multiple items is pulled from the database and displayed to the user, it runs a connection error.

Below is the route page (once the user has click on an item, it gets posted to this route page)

```
let sql = `SELECT box_id, cubby_id, occupied, comport
           FROM box
           WHERE longestDimension = ?
           AND LOWER(box_id) = LOWER(?)`;

    connection.query(sql, [boxSelectedDimension, boxSelectedValue] , function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
            for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) {
              // Make the comparaison case insensitive
              if (rows[i].occupied == `unoccupied`) {
                console.log("unoccupied");


          var comport = rows[i].comport;
          var command = "open" + rows[i].cubby_id;
          var commandClose = "close" + rows[i].cubby_id;


          console.log(command);
          console.log(comport);


          var options = {
            scriptPath: 'python/scripts',
            args: [command, comport, commandClose] // pass arguments to the script here

          };


          PythonShell.run('controlLock.py', options, function (err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('results: %j', results);
          });
```

Again, no connection error is thrown with only one item being rendered, but it seems to have issues with multiple within the form. I am guessing the issue is in the view.

UPDATE

More code

```
// Using post instead of get because a form was submitted with the method post
router.post('/', function(req, res){

    // Store the box location in the form of box_id
    var boxSelectedValue= req.body.boxSelectedValue;
    var boxSelectedDimension = req.body.boxSelectedDimension;
  var userHashtag = req.body.userHashtag;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the generated HTML (what the browser sees with View/Source) when there is more than one item in the form so we can see the actual HTML that the browser sees and don't have to try to figure out what it might be from the template.  Also, can you show us the higher level code from the route that leads to the code in your last code block?

Comment: My guess is that `boxSelectedDimension` and `boxSelectedValue` are not what you want when more than one item are selected, but we don't have enough code here to tell how those variables are set.

Comment: I added more code to show how boxSelectedValue, and oxSelectedDimension is retrieved

Comment: Did you look at what `req.body.boxSelectedValue` and `req.body.boxSelectedDimension` are in the case that doesn't work?

Comment: When I do console log it shows the following [ 'Box11', 'Box11' ] and [ '18', '24' ] my guess is that when there is multiple items, despite you clicking 1 it records both data and thats what could be throwing the error because it needs to work with one

Comment: If you showed the actual generated HTML from the form, I could advise further on the form. Right now you just shown a submit button that is, of course, going to post the WHOLE form, no matter which button was pushed.  It appears to me that you will get the same form posted no matter which button is pushed.  You will need to create a way in your form for each separate button that is submitted to create a different posted form so your server can tell which button was pushed.

Comment: Thanks. The HTML is in the view, but the view is rendered by handlebars template language. I include a picture of the page with the console log to the right.

Comment: Yes I agree. Create a way sto eperate submission for each item dynamically rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of to fix it would be to put each button in a separate form that each has a separate dimension set in it.  Then, the dimension you get in the form post would be the only the one for the button that was pressed.

My handlebars might be a bit rusty, but perhaps something like this:

```
{{#each rows}}

    <form method="post" action="/delivery/chooseBoxSelected">
        <input type="hidden" name="userHashtag" value="{{userHashtag}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="boxSelectedValue" value="{{this.box_id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="boxSelectedDimension" value="{{this.longestDimension}}">

        <button class="btn-dimension" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            &nbsp;Longest dimension {{this.longestDimension}}"
        </button>
    </form>
{{/each}}
```

And, you may have to adjust the CSS to deal with the fact that this is now N separate forms (one for each button).